# Principal Cast to JwtAuthenticationToken (cas Exception)

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I have a Spring Boot controller class where one of the methods, establishConnection, takes a Principal as a parameter. Inside this method, I'm trying to access some JWT claims from the principal using JwtAuthenticationToken. However, when I write a unit test for this method and use the @WithMockUser annotation, the principal generated in the test context is of type UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, not JwtAuthenticationToken. This causes issues in my test.

Here's a simplified version of my controller method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("stream/visite")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class VisiteStreamController {

    private final VisiteStreamManager visitesStreamManager;

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent<Long>> establishConnection(Principal principal) {
        // Attempt to access JWT claims, but the principal is of type UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.
        String guerite = ((JwtAuthenticationToken) principal).getTokenAttributes().get("guerite").toString();
        // Rest of the method...
    }
}
```

And here's my test method:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser
public void testEstablishConnection() {
    String gueriteHeaderValue = "your-guerite-value";

    // Perform the test...
}
```

I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.2 and Java 8. How can I configure the test so that the Principal in the test context is of type JwtAuthenticationToken rather than UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken?

I tried some codes found on the Internet but nothing worked